# Unknown column 'quantity' in 'field list' mySQL Wordpress php

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am trying to submit some data into a SQL database. The site runs on word press, however, whenever I do I get this error back:
"Unknown column 'quantity' in 'field list'

quantity is in the table. The request is below

```
global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->flush();
    $formatted = [
        'user_id' => $data['user_id'],
        'order_id' => $data['order_id'],
        'cable_type' => $data['cable']['type'],
        'cable_part_number' => $data['cable']['cable_part_number'],
        'wire_id' => $data['cable']['wire_id'],
        'cable_length_mm' => $data['cable']['mm'],
        'cable_length_inches' => $data['cable']['inches'],
        'connector_one' => $data['connectors'][0]['connector'],
        'contact_1' => $data['cable']['contact_1'],
        'connector_two' => isset($data['connectors'][1]) ? $data['connectors'][1]['connector'] : null,
        'contact_2' => isset($data['cable']['contact_2']) ? $data['cable']['contact_2'] : null,
        'no_of_contacts' => $data['cable']['no_of_contacts'],
        'cable_size' => $data['wireSize'],
        'backpot_type' => $data['cable']['backpot_type'],
        'crimp_type' => $data['cable']['crimp_type'],
        'leadtime' => $data['cable']['leadtime'],
        'quantity' => $data['leadtime']
    ];

    $result = $wpdb->insert('hw_cg_cable_orders', $formatted,
    ['%d','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%d','%s','%s','%s','%d','%d']);
```

Query to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `hw_cg_cable_orders` (


`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cable_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cable_part_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wire_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cable_length_mm` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cable_length_inches` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `connector_one` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `connector_two` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `no_of_contacts` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cable_size` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `backpot_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crimp_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `leadtime` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```